# Can't create table "system_user" in h2

Tags: java, h2

i am having a problem creating a simple table in h2.

`create table system_user (id bigint not null, username varchar(255), primary key (id));`

When executing i am getting the error:

```
Syntax Fehler in SQL Befehl "create table [*]system_user (id bigint not null, username varchar(255), primary key (id))"; erwartet "identifier"
Syntax error in SQL statement "create table [*]system_user (id bigint not null, username varchar(255), primary key (id))"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
create table system_user (id bigint not null, username varchar(255), primary key (id)) [42001-210] 42001/42001 (Hilfe)
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax Fehler in SQL Befehl "create table [*]system_user (id bigint not null, username varchar(255), primary key (id))"; erwartet "identifier"
Syntax error in SQL statement "create table [*]system_user (id bigint not null, username varchar(255), primary key (id))"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
create table system_user (id bigint not null, username varchar(255), primary key (id)) [42001-210]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:521)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:496)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:265)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readIdentifier(Parser.java:5759)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readIdentifierWithSchema(Parser.java:5719)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readIdentifierWithSchema(Parser.java:5748)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateTable(Parser.java:9280)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreate(Parser.java:6779)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:746)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:674)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:644)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:551)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:615)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:553)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:237)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:223)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.getResult(WebApp.java:1339)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.query(WebApp.java:1137)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp$1.next(WebApp.java:1103)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp$1.next(WebApp.java:1090)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.process(WebThread.java:189)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.run(WebThread.java:102)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: How are you creating the table?

Comment: The problem came when executing a Liquibase script. But it also occurs in the webconsole. The version of H2 is 2.1.210. The Liquibase script was working with the 1.x versions

Comment: Looking through their repo, i see that system_user is a "reserved" word. https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/03cc5c06536e4cc9e0bfe32ab5e5863f707e6dda/h2/src/test/org/h2/test/unit/TestKeywords.java hmmm.